# Getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running androidTest instrumented Tests of Espresso

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

When I Run the Espresso tests in Android Studio I get this error. I tried importing DaggerRuntime but still no help.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory
    at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.initialize(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:66)
    at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.<init>(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:54)
    at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.<init>(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:40)
    at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent$Builder.build(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:123)
    at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.create(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:62)
    at android.support.test.espresso.GraphHolder.baseLayer(GraphHolder.java:42)
    at android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.<clinit>(Espresso.java:51)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing support library in your build.gradle file

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
}
```